# local thresholding implementation in C++ / OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to implement a local thresholding algorithm and I require your expertise.

my images are resized to 600x400, grayscale.

Basic Thought process on localizing:

- Segment the images using a 9x9 ROI taken at each pixel and calculating the maximum intensity in the region.
- create a 9x9 Kernel.

  condition:

  - if the center pixel of the mask is above 50% of the maximum intensity, set the center pixel true.(apply mask)

my question to you:

- How should I pick my kernel/mask ?

  ```
    cv::Mat ROI;
    cv::Mat mask(input.size(),CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar::all(0)); // create mask of 0s at first
    const int kerneldepth = 1;
    const int kernelsize = 9;
    cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::ones( kernelsize, kernelsize, CV_8UC1 );


  //take ROI of 9x9 and apply a threshold

  for( double x = 9; x < input.cols -9; x++ ){
       for( double y = 9 ; y < input.rows - 9 ; y++ ){

          try{
            double x_left = x - 4;
            double x_right = x + 4;
            double y_up = y + 4;
            double y_down = y - 4;
            double maxVal;
            double minVal;
            cv::Point anchor(kernelsize/2,kernelsize/2);

            cv::Rect ROI = cv::Rect(x_left,y_down,9,9);
            cv::Mat ROI_Mat = input(ROI);                                // a new matrix for ROI
            cv::Scalar avgPixelIntensity = cv::mean( ROI_Mat );          // calculate mean
            cv::minMaxLoc(ROI_Mat,&minVal,&maxVal);

            if( input.at<uchar>(x,y) >= 0.5*maxVal){

            cv::filter2D(input,mask,-1,kernel,anchor,0);
      } else { break;}

      }

      catch (cv::Exception &e){

          e.what();
      }


     }

    *****************************UPDATED CODE: ******************************************

      applyLocalThresh(cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat& out){
        double maxVal, minVal;
        cv::Mat output;
        int top, bottom, left , right;
        int borderType = cv::BORDER_CONSTANT;
        cv::Scalar value;
        top = (int) (9); bottom = (int) (9);
        left = (int) (9); right = (int) (9);
        output = src;
        out = src;
        value = 0;
        cv::copyMakeBorder(src,output,top,bottom,left,right,borderType,value);

       for(int y = 9; y < src.rows; y++) {

          for(int x = 9; x < src.cols; x ++) {

                  cv::Mat ROI = src(cv::Rect(cv::Point(x-4,y-4),cv::Size(9,9)));
                  cv::minMaxLoc(ROI,&minVal,&maxVal);

          if(src.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x-4,y-4)) >= 0.6*maxVal){

          out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x-4,y-4)) = 255;
      }else{
          out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x-4,y-4));

          }
      }
  }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further thinking and finding out how to utilize my basic knowledge in programming, I came up with this code that isn't the most efficient but gets the job done.

What was the main problem with my approach? :

- Boundary pixels where one of the main problems and the whole indexing operation between kernel and mask caused a slight headache.

What was my approach in solving that matter?:

- My threshold says it needs a relative high intensity level to set true pixels. Therefore I filled the image with some imaginary negative pixels and made my algorithm start at the first pixel of the original. And saved the results to a mask.

Result:

- SUCCESS!

Code:

```
     double maxVal, minVal;
     cv::Mat output;
     int top, bottom, left , right;
     int borderType = cv::BORDER_CONSTANT;
     cv::Scalar value;
     top = (int) (4); bottom = (int) (4);
     left = (int) (4); right = (int) (4);
     output = src;
     out = src;
     value = 0;
     cv::copyMakeBorder(src,output,top,bottom,left,right,borderType,value);

for(int y = 4; y < output.rows - 4; y++) {

    for(int x = 4; x < output.cols - 4; x ++) {

        // apply local ROI

        cv::Mat ROI = output(cv::Rect(cv::Point(x-4,y-4),cv::Size(9,9)));
        cv::minMaxLoc(ROI,&minVal,&maxVal);    // extract max intensity values in the ROI

        if(src.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x-4,y-4)) >= 0.5*maxVal){    // apply local threshold w.r.t highest intensity level

            out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x-4,y-4)) = 255;            // change pixel value in mask if true
        }else{
            out.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x-4,y-4)) = 0;

            }

        }
    }



}
```

it needs some clean up I know but hopefully this would help others to get some idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a dilation followed by a comparison in OpenCV;

```
im = load image here;
di = dilate im with a 9x9 kernel;
bw = im > (di * 0.5); // in OpenCV, pixels of bw are set to 255 or 0
```

A simple example to illustrate this with a 4x6 image and a 3x3 kernel in Matlab/Octave:

im =

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6
 2     3     4     5     6     7
 3     4     5     6     7     8
 4     5     6     7     8     9
```

di =

```
 3     4     5     6     7     7
 4     5     6     7     8     8
 5     6     7     8     9     9
 5     6     7     8     9     9
```

th = di * .5

th =

```
1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    3.5000
2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.0000
2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    4.5000
2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    4.5000
```

bw = im > th

bw =

```
 0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: this is a really good explanation, however would this deliver the same as actually moving through each pixel and figuring out the local maximum to take as true ? Because actually its basically a comparison more than any actual conv process.

Answer (score 2):

I fear this approach is not entirely correct. Let me explain: for operations involving a kernel, one must be careful to place **the center of the kernel** on top of the pixel that is going to be transformed. That's because a 3x3, 5x5, 7x7, 9x9 (...) kernel just computes the value for **one pixel** in the image, which is the one positioned at the center [0,0] of the kernel.

If you think about how to compute the value for the first pixel of the image, the center of a 9x9 kernel is going to be placed at coordinate **[0,0]**. That means that 3/4 of the kernel are going to be placed at negative coordinates, i.e. coordinates that refers to pixels that don't exist:

```
 [-4,-4][-3,-4][-2,-4][-1,-4][ 0,-4][ 1,-4][ 2,-4][ 3,-4][ 4,-4]
 [-4,-3][-3,-3][-2,-3][-1,-3][ 0,-3][ 1,-3][ 2,-3][ 3,-3][ 4,-3]
 [-4,-2][-3,-2][-2,-2][-1,-2][ 0,-2][ 1,-2][ 2,-2][ 3,-2][ 4,-2]
 [-4,-1][-3,-1][-2,-1][-1,-1][ 0,-1][ 1,-1][ 2,-1][ 3,-1][ 4,-1]
 [-4, 0][-3, 0][-2, 0][-1, 0][ 0, 0][ 1, 0][ 2, 0][ 3, 0][ 4, 0]
 [-4, 1][-3, 1][-2, 1][-1, 1][ 0, 1][ 1, 1][ 2, 1][ 3, 1][ 4, 1]
 [-4, 2][-3, 2][-2, 2][-1, 2][ 0, 2][ 1, 2][ 2, 2][ 3, 2][ 4, 2]
 [-4, 3][-3, 3][-2, 3][-1, 3][ 0, 3][ 1, 3][ 2, 3][ 3, 3][ 4, 3]
 [-4, 4][-3, 4][-2, 4][-1, 4][ 0, 4][ 1, 4][ 2, 4][ 3, 4][ 4, 4]
```

**This is always going to happen with pixels near the border of the image.** So for the computation of the first pixel, we would have to restrict the computation to 1/4 of the kernel, which refers to valid coordinates in the target image:

```
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ][     ]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][ 0, 0][ 1, 0][ 2, 0][ 3, 0][ 4, 0]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][ 0, 1][ 1, 1][ 2, 1][ 3, 1][ 4, 1]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][ 0, 2][ 1, 2][ 2, 2][ 3, 2][ 4, 2]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][ 0, 3][ 1, 3][ 2, 3][ 3, 3][ 4, 3]
 [     ][     ][     ][     ][ 0, 4][ 1, 4][ 2, 4][ 3, 4][ 4, 4]
```

So the problem with your current approach is that at some point you will setup a ROI that is going to have negative coordinates, and when these instructions are executed you will see a nice crash:

```
cv::Mat ROI_Mat = input(ROI);  // crash
```

The solution is not to use a ROI and just implement that algorithm yourself. I just can't see this custom computation working with `cv::filter2D()`. Here's a little something to help you get started:

```
void local_threshold(const cv::Mat& input, cv::Mat& output)
{
    if (input.channels() != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "local_threshold !!! input image must be single channel" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    output = cv::Mat(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC1);
    double min_val = 0, max_val = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < input.cols; j++)
        {
            cv::Mat kernel = Mat::zeros(9, 9, output.type());

            // Implement logic to fill the 9x9 kernel with
            // values from the input Mat, respecting boundaries.

            cv::Scalar avg_intensity = cv::mean(kernel);
            cv::minMaxLoc(kernel, &min_val,&max_val);

            if (input.at<uchar>(i,j) > (max_val / 2))
                output.at<unsigned char>(i,j) = 255;
            else
                output.at<unsigned char>(i,j) = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: great detailed answer! this has cleared up some of the questions regarding kernels. Thanks! I will take your advice in consideration.

Comment: I tried implementing this with no success. I did the following steps: 
- create the kernel
- get values inside a certain range of the image and save it temporarily to the kernel
- make the comparison, if true save as true
- save in a new matrix output at the same range
however I get assertion errors after certain iterations and I can't put my finger on it. Please advise

Comment: if I add borders of black pixels, this should theoretically make me skip the whole headache with border pixels. I would let my loop start from the 4th row or column and stop before it becomes out of range.